# Twitter Bootstrap: Uncaught TypeError: Object modal1 has no method 'toggle'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently made a change to have some icons be the buttons that make a twitter-bootstrap modal appear on my site, and I am now getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object modal1 has no method 'toggle'

The modals are appearing cut off, or are not appearing at all in some cases (there are many that have been created dynamically).  Here is the relevant code:

The Button HTML:

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal-{{$artist->id}}" class="Details">
                                  <span class="fa-stack">
                                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                  <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x"></i>
                                  </span> 
    </a>
```

Modal HTML:

```
  <div id="myModal-{{$artist->id}}" class="modal hide fade side-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></button>
    </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <article class="musicainDEtailImgBox"> <a href="#"><img src="{{$artist->image_path}}" alt="" title="" width="240" height="240"></a>
            <h5>{{$artist->stage_name}}</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Any idea why this is occurring?  I am using font awesome icons for the icons.

EDIT:

The javascript console error references line 1008 of bootstrap.js:

```
if (!data) $this.data('modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
```

Comment: Please post your script include or a demo on jsfiddle

Comment: are you using bootstrap 2.x.x or 3.x.x? in bs 3, there is no class `hide` for modal.

Comment: I tried making a jsfiddle...but it looks like a fail. Does it even do modals?  Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Dn8Mx/1/

I tried adding all of the external files I am using.  jquery is 1.9.1 and bootstrap files are 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

It seems either:

1. The inclusion of Font Awesome scripts have interfered with the correct loading of Bootstrap scripts
   *or*
2. The Font Awesome icons are preventing the click event on your 'a'.

Can you provide source code on http://www.bootply.com/?

Comment: I can still click on the font awesome icons.  And some of the modals will appear.  But some won't...  And some will only partially appear.  Very strange.

Comment: The screen still fades.

Comment: I removed the font awesome icons, and the issue is still occurring.